# What's a convenient way to execute multiline queries in postgres using ssh?

Tags: postgresql

Say I need hand write some queries in the console, what's the most efficient way of executing multiline queries like `CREATE TABLE` statements?

I am used to using Microsoft Management Studio, but I now find myself having to learn about PostgreSQL on the fly.

Comment: Type it in? Copy and paste? Redirect from a file?

Comment: Yes I mean type it in with my fingers :P.  What I'm getting at is that the postgres `#` prompt appears only enter one line at a time which is great for things like `CREATE DATABASE` or `ALTER USER`.  How would I be able to nicely format my text before executing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following will take you to PostgreSQL's interactive terminal:

```
$ psql <your database name>
```

Then enter `\e` (or `\edit`) to open an editor (`vi` is default):

```
# \e
```

Write some query:

```
select now();
```

Finally, save and quit your editor (e.g. `:wq` in `vi`), and `psql` will run the query you just wrote.

To set a different editor, such as `vim` or `nano`, set one of the following environment variables: `PSQL_EDITOR`, `EDITOR`, `VISUAL`.

For more information, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html and search for `\e`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this syntax in bash (.sh file):

```bash
psql postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres << SQL
CREATE TABLE "public"."links" (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  from_id bigint DEFAULT 0,
  to_id bigint DEFAULT 0,
  type_id bigint NOT NULL
);
SQL
```

Answer (score 7):

There is really no such thing as a "multi-line query" - as far as PostgreSQL cares, all that whitespace and those newlines are meaningless (unless they occur inside a string or we're talking about tabs & such in a `COPY` statement or a few other special places).

Writing queries "on the console" over SSH is usually done with the `psql` tool, which is the Postgres interactive terminal (see the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for more info).

You can pass *text files containing queries* to `psql` using the `-f` option.

You can also pass queries to `psql` on the command line (quoted as appropriate for your shell), or pipe them in via STDIN (the standard input stream) - see the `-c` option.

Comment: Pipes, should have thought about pipes.  I still learn.

Answer (score 7):

Obvious, but if anyone is not aware, you can write multi-line statements directly in the psql prompt:

```sh
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres public
public=# SELECT
public=# *
public=# FROM
public=# mytable
public=# LIMIT 1;
```

Note the trailing `;` character - any SQL command will only be executed once this character has been issued. So the easiest way is to simply copy & paste multi-line SQL commands with a trailing `;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the query to a temp file and execute it with `psql -f /path/to/temp/file`